# CSS hover rule needs to apply to parent only

Tags: html, css

I have a simple textbox inside a div, and I want a hover rule to apply when hovering over the div but *not* the textbox.

Code:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid #777777; padding:16px; background-color:#eeeeee;">
    <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
</div>
```

```
#div1:hover {
    background-color:#ffffff !important;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8NRNQ/1/)

When hovering over the textbox, the div's hover rule must not apply. Is there a way to do this without JavaScript?

Comment: I can't think of a way to make this possible without using Javascript.

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS like this way. You need to put the `input` outside the div with fixed positions, but I'd not recommend that.

Comment: Did you try z-index for your textbox?

Comment: @hicurin z-index also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I ended up using JavaScript:

```
$('#div1').mouseover(function () {
    var el = $(this).find('input');
    if (!(el.hasClass('inputishover'))) {
        $(this).addClass('divhover');
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('divhover');
});

$('#div1 input').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('inputishover');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('inputishover');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8NRNQ/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for..? Please see the fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" >
  <div id="div1" style="">
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1:hover{
 background-color:red !important;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#container{
 position:absolute;
}
#div1{
 position:absolute;
 display:block; 
 border:1px solid #777777; 
 padding:16px; 
 width: 180px;
 background-color:#eeeeee;
}

#txt1{
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 background-color:white !important;
 position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8NRNQ/4/

Comment: This is correct, just as MikaldL said in the comments. Only way I can think to do it too.

Comment: Thanks. It works but I don't like the absolute positions. Guess javascript is the answer.

Comment: @user982119 Javascript would be better, its a simple. `input.hover -> add class to #div1 -> that class would set the background back to none hover background`.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you are looking for?**

```
#div1 { display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #777777; 
padding:16px; 
background-color:#eeeeee;
}

#div1:hover {
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Testing Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8NRNQ/3/

Comment: Thats not what they are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one simple line of JS for that. The problem is, that you can't change the background of the containing div with hover over the input just by CSS. But in jQuery for example, this is pretty easy

```
$('#div1 input').hover(function(){$(this).parent.css(SET BACKGROUND AND CURSOR BACK TO THE NO-HOVER-STYLE)});
```